# Configure dnsmasq to listen on public IP instead of only LAN

Tags: raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

I am trying to host a DNS server with dnsmasq using my Raspberry Pi. I can connect to the DNS server through LAN but I am not able to connect to it through my public IP. I already have port 53 forwarded on my router.

/etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
server=1.1.1.1
server=1.0.0.1
interface=wlan0
address=/test.example.com/127.0.0.1
```